# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

Trying to integrate Location Client into my app,
searched for this problem found [Failed to resolve: om.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990166/failed-to-resolve-om-google-android-gmsplay-services-location15-0-1)

Below are my gradle build files

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.findme"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

And

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to resolve: om.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990166/failed-to-resolve-om-google-android-gmsplay-services-location15-0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version `16.1.0` for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` doesn't exist as you can see here on the [release notes page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

You may use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0` or `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0`

Comment: Thanks sir, I forget to check the release notes